# Minimum rounds to exchange information among n people

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, puzzle

Suppose there are $n$ people and all of them have unique information. In one round, two people can interact and tell each other all information they know. In total, how many round may be required so that everyone knows all $n$ pieces of information?

I could not prove it but after going over some examples $n = 4, 5, 6, 8$, I found it to obey $f(n) = 2\cdot n - 4$, but I dont know if this is the minimum. How can we find minimum number?

Comment: It is an easy induction to show $f(n+1)\le f(n)+2$ - interact with the new person at the beginning and end.

Comment: $2n-4$ is correct for $n \ge 4$.  See [OEIS A058992](https://oeis.org/A058992) where this is called the Gossip Problem.  https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/PUZZLES/gossips.pdf has a proof

Comment: @Henry thanks a lot that is helpful